# Can you have too many models in a PHP mvc?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, oop

I'm currently creating my own PHP mvc for a site that I run so that it will include just  the code needed yo be as light and fast as possible.

The site has quite a large range of functions and user features so working out which actions go where in which models controlled by which controllers is starting to get quite complex.

**Example**

Say I have the following member features

- Favourites
- Friends
- History

Each of those can be controlled by the **membercontroller** but then my question is whether to have them all inside one model or a model for each.

Each of those three has sub many actions such as:

- Add to favourites
- Remove favourites
- Show favourites
- Add to history
- Remove history
- Show history
- Add as friend
- Remove friend
- Message friend

...etc

At the moment I'm thinking a model for each (favourite, friends, history) is probably the best way, but can it get to a point where you have too many models?

At the moment the whole site has 6 controllers, 17 models and 25 views

Comment: What do you mean by 'model' in this context? Database entities? Groups of DB entities? Something else?

Comment: Kind of model per group of actions related to a certain site function/group. So memberactions could be a model or favourites/friends/history could all be separate models instead of memberactions.

Comment: @Silver89: a Model in MVC is usually an abstraction layer to your data. I reckon that favorites is a different set of data than friends are, and you might want to perform different actions on it (read: Favorites model can tell you/do different things than Friends model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can technically have too many models, there is a limit (as always) of how many classes can exist in PHP. But it's pretty large, so keep on going. You can not only have many but also different kind of models at once. So keep on going, don't restrain your coding by thinking there might be a limit you don't see so far.

So not the count of files, but how nicely written your code is, e.g. is everything grouped properly that belongs together? See as well [Domain Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you let `ModelController` deal with actions that somehow modify `Model`.

I.e. `FavoritesController` deals with adding, removing and showing favorites (stored on `FavoritesModel`). Keeps your controllers lean/slim, is a lot easier to test (less methods) and keeps logical app parts together.

Also, you could divide the application into smaller apps that deal each with:

- Auth/Login
- Social/Sharing
- add/read/show articles (main app)

Comment: So with an mvc it doesn't matter so much how many files you have as long as the structure is simple to understand and it's sensible? vs grouping as much together as possible?

Comment: MVC separates the tasks that each application part does. I.e. a view only knows how to "render" a specific model. Now, let's say you have a view that outputs `html` and one that outputs `json`. You can write the code however you prefer (one file, two methods OR two files OR an abstract view with common functionality and two concrete views that extend it). As far as the many files are concerned, I'd say you don't worry if you have too many files, this is probably why you are refactoring your app in the first place ;)

Comment: A view should only interact with view models, not with domain or database models.

Comment: @hakre: I never specified what kind of models I was referring to :)

Comment: @hakre: otoh, I think you are more precisely referring to the MVVM (model, view, view-model, something like knockout.js) pattern, which is not what the question was about ;)

Comment: @Oerd: If you like to exchange opinions: What you call MVC looks more like *transaction scripts* which is not a bad idea to start with btw. - And no, I don't refer to terms that get invented to just destroy talking about design but refer to the documented terms like GoF and PoEAA and I suggest you to do, too.

Comment: @hakre: thing is, I just recently ran into knockout.js and the `view-model` concept. On your suggestion, I have to admit that web-based (and mostly) CRUD apps are bound be somehow limited to being /transaction scripts/ there is of course a lot more that can be done, but I acknowledge that my answer refers to what looks like /transaction scripts/ :) thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios there is no "right" answer, so all I can give you is my own interpretation. I would use a service to do bind one or more models together. So, a User service would use the User model and the Favourite model to manipulate and display user favourites.